# search results or search result count - ngx-treeview

Tags: angular, ngx-treeview

I am using a ngx-treeview with custom headerTemplate. I want to disable the select all input when the search results are empty. From the treeview template i can get the config & the item.

```
<ng-template #headerTemplate
             let-item="item"
             let-config="treeViewCategoryConfig"
             let-onCheckedChange="onCheckedChange "
             let-onFilterTextChange="onFilterTextChange">
  <div *ngIf="treeViewCategoryConfig.hasFilter">
    <input type="search"
           [(ngModel)]="filter"
           (ngModelChange)="onFilterTextChange($event)"
           #filterCategory />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"
           value=""
           [ngModel]="checked"
           (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)"
           [id]="checkboxId" />
    <label class="form-check-label"
           [for]="checkboxId">
        {{label}}
    </label>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

```
export interface TreeviewHeaderTemplateContext {
    config: TreeviewConfig;
    item: TreeviewItem;
    onCollapseExpand: () => void;
    onCheckedChange: (checked: boolean) => void;
    onFilterTextChange: (text: string) => void;
}
```

ngx-treeview emits the selected values from `selectedChange` event but not the search results. `onFilterTextChange` method performs the search but returns void.

Comment: Could you add a StackBlitz to your question?

Comment: here is the library source - https://github.com/leovo2708/ngx-treeview and the gh-page - https://leovo2708.github.io/ngx-treeview/#/components

Comment: I found a solution to this. I added a template reference variable for the ngx-treeview and pass that variable as a parameter from the template for any click events. By doing this i can access the component instance and ngx-treeview component has a property - hasFilterItems. I tried accessing the ngx-treeview using the viewChild but it is not working.